# Target WSGI script can't be load as python module

Tags: python, flask, wsgi, flask-restful, werkzeug

Flask rest API throwing 500 error with 'Target WSGI script can't load as cannot be loaded as Python module' with below logs and in application .wsgi file all looks good.

```
 from flask import Flask, request, g
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/flask/__init__.py", line 17, in <module>
 from werkzeug.exceptions import abort
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/__init__.py", line 152, in <module>
  __import__('werkzeug.exceptions')
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/exceptions.py", line 71, in <module>
  from werkzeug.wrappers import Response
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/wrappers.py", line 26, in <module>
  from werkzeug.http import HTTP_STATUS_CODES, \\
 File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/http.py", line 28, in <module>
 from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
 ImportError: No module named request
```

When I debug through werkzeug/http.py file I came across the below code and in python command line `from urllib2 import parse_http_list` is working fine but in code, it is going to exception block.

```
from urllib2 import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
except ImportError:  # pragma: no cover
   from urllib.request import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
```

Answer (score 0):

The module `urllib.request` is for Python 3. You are using python 2.

From [Werkzeug 2.0.0 changelogs](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug/blob/master/CHANGES.rst):

> Drop support for Python 2 and 3.5

Either downgrade Werkzeug or upgrade to latest python 3 release.